# Is there a way to stop yarn latest-version check?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

In my corporate environment internet access is limited.  yarn seems to always check the latest-version resulting in:

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.27s.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 24.406830149 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 48.4054138 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 72.407100109 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 96.409950896 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
```

As one can see, this cost me 100 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

For yarn v1 you can do:

```sh
yarn config set disable-self-update-check true
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc#toc-disable-self-update-check